# Зачем вдруг понадобился worker-loader в vue.js проекте? И как его заставить работать?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Всем привет.

Мой проект на vue.js друг перестал собираться, даже тот коммит на котором все точно работало - больше не собирается.

При запуске npm run build ругается на отсутствие worker-loader:

Failed to resolve loader: worker-loader
You may need to install it.

После установки worker-loader, npm run build ругается следующим образом:

This dependency was not found:

- module in (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js

хотя файл node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js присутствует.

Знает ли кто-нибудь для чего нужен worker-loader и почему он вдруг понадобился? И как бы в целом побороть эту проблему?

Comment: Установите его вручную `npm i worker-loader`

Comment: Я его установил :)

> После установки worker-loader, npm run build ругается следующим образом:

> This dependency was not found:

> module in (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js
> хотя файл node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, дело в зависимостях. Может, очевидный совет, тем не менее:

1. Удалить /node_modules
2. Удалить /yarn.lock или /package-lock.json
3. Выполнить `yarn` или `npm i`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает :(